# Perform action when http resolves and throw error if needed

Tags: angular, http, rxjs

I'm trying to do the following with observables and I can't figure out what the best way would be to do it:

I'm calling a login endpoint using http. This service will return a token. I want to perform 2 different actions from 2 different points within the APP sequentially: when http resolves I need to store the provided token and then show a message. I tried the following:

```
return this.http.get(this.config.getApi('login'), params)
           .map(response => response.json())
           .do((data) => {
               // Store token here
               // If it fails, throw error
               // Tried Observable.throw here but the subscriber doesn't get it.
            }).subscribe(
               (data) => {
                  // Everything went fine
                },
               () => {
                  // Either the http request failed or 
                 // the process of storing the token threw an error.
            }
       );
```

Unfortunately, the subscribers to the returned observable never get error unless the http call fails. What operator should I use instead of do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand you want to do this :

```
do http call 
    then do something else 
       if error   
           throw error
    subscribe 
        handle success
        handle error
```

One way I can think of to do this, is using a `flatMap` . Rewriting your code

```
return this.http.get(this.config.getApi('login'), params)
       .map(response => response.json())
       .flatMap((data) => {
           //do whatever you want to do , 
           // lets say error = true if something went wrong
           return error ? 
               Observable.throw('error message') :
               Observable.of(data);
        }).subscribe(...);
```

[JSBIN](https://jsbin.com/didiqemipe/edit?html,js,console,output) link with a simple illustration

Comment: This is exactly it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You should be `subscribing` to access the response

```
this.http.get(this.config.getApi('login'), params)
                .map(response => response.json())
                .subscribe(data=>{
                     console.log(data);
       });
```

Comment: What I wanted to do is run the code to store my token and then return the observable so someone else could subscribe. If the token store operation fails, the method that subscribes to that observable should get an error. Forgot to add the subscribe to my example.

Comment: where you want to store it ? and why? you are asking throwing an error inside the do or??

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
import { isDevMode } from '@angular/core';
import { _throw } from 'rxjs/observable/throw';


return this.http.get(this.config.getApi('login'), params)
.map(r => r.json())
.do(data => {
  this.token = data; //an instance variable defined in your service class
  if(isDevMode()) console.log(data) // display log only in devMode (why would you want to log something in console in production?! :D)
})
.catch(error => _throw(JSON.stringify(error));
```

Ofc you need to invoke this method from outside (component,guard,etc) so that the http request is executed

Comment: then you could add the condition inside of the do